# Show completeness of metric subspace

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I have problems solving the following 2 problems:

> Given is the metric $d:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to[0,\infty[$ with
>
> $$d(x,y):=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|\;.$$
>
> a) Show that the metric subspace $\big([-1,1], d\mid\big([-1,1]\times[-1,1]\big)\big)$ is complete.

(I had to show before that the space as a whole is not complete which I already did.)

> b) Is $[-1,1]$ in $(\Bbb R, d)$ a compact set?

Thanks for your help in advance, and maybe someone could help with the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that $d$ is equivalent to the usual metric on $\Bbb R$, meaning that it generates the same topology on $\Bbb R$. Compactness is a topological property, not a metric property, so as long as two metrics generate the same topology, a set compact in one is compact in the other. Completeness then comes for free.

It’s also possible to show directly that $[-1,1]$ is complete with respect to $d$, but you’re doing essentially the same work: show that a $d$-Cauchy sequence in $[-1,1]$ is Cauchy with respect to the usual metric as well and therefore converges to some $x\in[-1,1]$ in the usual metric, and then show that it converges to $x$ with respect to $d$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I start showing that d is equivalent to the usual metric?

Comment: @bavor42: You’re welcome. Let $\rho$ be the usual metric. Show that each open $\rho$-ball $B_\rho(x,\epsilon)$ is open with respect to $d$ by showing that for each $y\in B_\rho(x,\epsilon)$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $B_d(y,\delta)\subseteq B_\rho(x,\epsilon)$, and then show similarly that each open $d$-ball is open in the usual metric.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how "Completeness then comes for free"? Completeness is not a topological invariant. Two metrics can be equivalent on X but one is complete on X, whereas other can be incomplete on X. metric space: (X,d)